# Why the id is diffrent between 'select *' and 'select id' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a table named  `account_info`.
When I run `select id from account_info limit 0, 10`,the result is as follows.

[image: ids]

But when I run `select * from acccount_info limit 0, 10`, the result is as follows(Other columns are ignored).

[image: ids]

Why the ids are different?
When I add `order by id` to these two sql, the results are same. It seems like is the order of result that matters. But I think when there is no `order by id`, both `select id from account_info limit 0, 10` and `select * from account_info` share the same default sort policy, and the result supposed to be same.

Can somebody explain why? My MySQL version is 5.7.14.

Comment: Data is not stored sequentially. If you do not use an `order by` then you get the data in whatever order it may actually be stored on the database, or whatever order the optimiser decides

Comment: Are you asking out of academic curiosity? If you don't specify an `order by` clause, then you should not expect any specific order. With exactly the same query it could (but rarely does) even change from execute to execute. This specific case might be the difference between being able to use an index scan to satisfy the query and having to scan the actual table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "default sort policy" as sorting always requires some (usually quite expensive) computation, so if you don't specify any order MySQL is free to return the rows the way it thinks is fastest / cheapest.

The reason why you see the values being sorted when you only query `id` is that in this case MySQL just needs to read the primary key which is stored as a (sorted) B-Tree. You can confirm this by looking at the query execution plan - it should display `Using index` which is described as :

> The column information is retrieved from the table using only
>   information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek
>   to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses
>   only columns that are part of a single index.

When you query `*` then MySQL has to go through the table data itself which can be stored in any order.

Please note that the above explanation is no guarantee on result sorting. To repeat: **without an explicit `ORDER BY` all bets are off on how the data is returned.**